# Spring Data Jpa OneToMany save child and parent entities at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, set, spring-data

This is my parent entity.
Note: Removing getters, setters, lombok annotations for brevity.

```
@Entity
public class Board {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board")
    private Set<Story> stories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Below is my child entity

```
@Entity
public class Story {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Board board;
}
```

Each `Board` can have multiple `Story`, but each `Story` belongs to single `Board`.

Now somewhere in my service, I am doing this:

```
public void addBoard(BoardDTO boardDto){
    // create a new board object which is just a pojo
    // by copying properties from boardDto
    Board board = ...;

    // create set of stories
    List<String> defaultTitles = Arrays.asList("Todo", "In-Progress", "Testing", "Done");
    Set<Story> stories = defaultTitles.stream().map(title -> Story.builder()
            .title(title)
            // assign a reference, I know this is wrong since board here is not
            // saved yet or fetched from db, hence the question
            .board(board) 
            .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // This saves board perfectly, but in Story db, the foreign key column
    // board_id is null, rightfully so since call to story table was not yet done.
    Board save = boardRepository.save(Board.builder()
            .title(board.getTitle())
            .stories(stories)
            .build());
}
```

One approach that I can take is to save the board first without `Set<Story>` and then do a save on stories with this saved board set as ref. But this would need two Repository calls and code wise it wouldn't look good.

Also, the reason why I am having trouble is because until I run this code, my db is empty. That is this is a new record that we are entering for the first time. So `Board table` has no rows yet.

So is there anyway to do this in a single shot? For most of the other questions on stackoverflow, the board entity is already fetched from db and **then** they are adding child entities to it and saving it to db. But for me, the db is completely fresh and I want to add a first new parent entity and its corresponding child entities at the same time, at least code wise even if hibernate makes multiple db calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to cascade the changes from the parent to the child:

```
@Entity
public class Board {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Story> stories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now whenever you save the parent (`Board`), the changes will cascade to the child table. You can also use `CascadeType.ALL` instead of `{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` to cascade any changes, like removal (when you remove the child from the collection on the parent entity, the joining id in the child table will be removed).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one small query. I have a cascade on child entity as you can see in my question. Therefore in my parent table, two rows are being added. Of course I can remove cascade on my child entity. But what if I want to have that? how do I avoid this problem of having two rows being persisted onto my parent table?

Comment: Weird, if I remove cascade on my child entity, I get an error `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`. This is probably because `Story` is just a pojo and has not been saved. On the other hand, if I keep cascade on my child entity(along with cascade that you gave for parent entity), I end up seeing two rows in my parent entity. And what do you mean by updates? you mean `jpa.show-sql: true` updates?

Comment: So I just checked logs. There are two inserts sent to Board(parent) and 4 inserts into Story(child). 4 inserts into child entity makes sense because I have 4 elements in my defaultTitles list. But the 2nd insert for parent is weird. This is also messing up the board_id foreign key column in the child table, instead of being 1 its now 2(because of that 2nd row that got pushed into parent table).

Comment: Since the discussion is out of bounds of the answer, can we continue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207050/spring-data-jpa-onetomany-save-child-and-parent-entities-at-the-same-time ?

Comment: @theprogrammer Facing a similar issue. Were you able to figure this out?
Chat room link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ragavramachandran the OP used the solution described here and it worked: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/